# RESTful webservice with unknown number of parameters

Tags: java, json, rest

I am writing a RESTful web service using Java which should be able to take as (POST) input an unknown number of parameter name, value pairs. I am thinking what is the best way to achieve this.

The POST input will be JSON with the expected format being:

```
{"input" :
  { "x" = 1, "y"="Hello, "z"="1.2.3.4",... }
}
```

The parameter values are expected to be a mix of int/long/float/string etc. The expected behavior is to save this input to the DB and provide it back on request. The tricky part is with the parameter names being unknown, I cannot write getter and setter methods. Is there a simple way for handling this?

Any pointers in the right direction will be very much appreciated. Can I read this as a List? Do I need to write Custom MessageBodyReaders? Is there some other way of achieving this? The only option I can think of is to have these sent as a file and parse it but am hoping that there are simpler/cleaner solutions. Thank you for any pointers...

Comment: I'm confused. Which table are you writing to? Where is your key? If you have both, you can have a url schema with GET/PUT/POST based on those.

Comment: I simplified the example. I will be writing to a DB table and the input request will have other parameters outside of the example array shown above which will constitute the primary key of the table - The question is for the attributes in the input array, can I save these as a HashMap? Dave replied that I should save that as a String. So am trying to explore how I can save the entire request as a String w/o getter and setter for individual fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is save it and make it available on request, why parse it at all?  Simply write the json as a string to your database, and return it as a string while setting the response type to "application/json".  The one caveat being you're going to have to have some way to identify which json string you want and associate a unique id that you're going to be able to determine when you're requesting the specific json string in the future.

Something worth noting here would be that when you don't parse something, you don't actually know what it is.  Even though a lot of modern libraries/frameworks sanitize against sql injection/xss already, it would be worth it to verify that this is being done in your server if you don't already know for sure.

That being said, if you're still feeling as though you need to parse the json, I would look into gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Dave, Thank you for your reply. I would be okay with saving the entire string as json. What I am trying to figure out is how though I parse the entire message body as a String. I know how to write getter and setters on fields within the message body and parse those. Am I missing something very obvious? :(

Comment: Which webserver are you using?  Or did you do something like write your own (maybe for a school project)?

Comment: I am using JBoss as the web server, with RestEasy for developing the Restful API

Comment: I've never used JAX-RS, but I read a little bit on the documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html and it looks as though you should just be able to use the @consumes("text/plain") to get the contents of the request into a variable.

Comment: Dave, Thank you very much for pointing me in the correct direction. This is my first time with web services, and I really appreciate your help. I can now parse the entire POST body to a string!!